# Setting an onchange event when the browser reloads

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code that works fine in the respect that it shows the input box when yes is selected.  My issue is if there is an error with any of the other boxes during the submit and the placeholder dropdown is set to yes it does not show the placeholderValue input box.

How could I adjust this code so if my code does error and if the input box is set to yes it will display the placeholderValue input box.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#add_fields_placeholder").change(function()
        {
            if($(this).val() == "yes")
        {
            $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').show();
            $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").show();
        }
        else
        {

            $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').hide();
            $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").hide();
        }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to trigger your `<select>`'s change event manually after the validation code makes the update: `$("#add_fields_placeholder").trigger("change");`

Comment: Thanks for that,  I am very new to jQuery and custom development,  Would I place this within the above code or create a php function?  Were does "change" come from?

Comment: "change" is the event handle for when the select box is changed with user input. If your validation is on the client side (in javascript) place the above right after you make the update to the select box. If it is done on the server side(in your php) then you would have to manually show the input box in when you re-render the page.

Comment: Thanks,  Are you able to give me a php re-render example?

Comment: If you are validating in the php, you will need to check for values passed into the script in the part that renders out the page. Then you set the values to what was passed in. Based on those passed in values you should set the input to hide or show (display: none for hide). I don't have php specific but look at how your validation code gets the var's (believe it is $_POST or something like that sorry I'm a perl dev). Are you doing a form post back to the php for validation or ajax?