# PHP Validation and hidden dropdown box

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an Placeholder Value input box that is set to `display:none;` on page load due to it being controlled jQuery and shows when the Placeholder dropdown box is selected to yes.

My issue is that I have used the Codeigniter Validation for the form and if I have an error on the form the page reloads the Placeholder dropdown box states yes but the Placeholder Value input box disappears.

Would my best bet be to create a callback_ function that basically states if yes is selected show the input box?

**jQuery:**

```
              $("#add_fields_placeholder").change(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == "yes")
    {
        $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').show();
        $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").show();
    }
    else
    {

        $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').hide();
        $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").hide();
    }
        });
```

**View:**

```
<label for="add_fields_placeholder">Placeholder: </label>
<select name="add_fields_placeholder" id="add_fields_placeholder">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="yes" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','yes', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "yes" ? TRUE : FALSE ));?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="no" <?php echo set_select('add_fields_placeholder','no', ( !empty($placeholderType) && $placeholderType == "no" ? TRUE : FALSE ));?>>No</option>
</select>

<label for="add_fields_placeholderValue">Placeholder Text: </label>
<input type="text" name="add_fields_placeholderValue" id="add_fields_placeholderValue" value="<?php echo set_value('add_fields_placeholderValue'); ?>">
```

**Controller Validation:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fields_placeholder', 'Placeholder', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_dropdown_check');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fields_placeholderValue', 'Placeholder Text','trim|xss_clean');
```

Comment: I guess you need to check the actual state of the `dropdown` so every time your page loads you'll check the state and make the necessary changes to the other field. I think that this question is not PHP related since there is no PHP errors so if I'm not mistaken could you please change the tags? =)

Comment: You used javascript to display the hidden field? If so, you just need to call this also in the load of the page ;)

Comment: @SérgioMichels Could you provide me an example it seems I could not get one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961248/setting-an-onchange-event-when-the-browser-reloads I was thinking this was the case

Comment: @JessMcKenzie please, post your code that shows the hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads, you will need to trigger the change of the `add_fields_placeholder`. Just make sure that the yes option is selected. The code will be something like:

```
function initChangeEvent() {
  $("#add_fields_placeholder").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "yes") {
        $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').show();
        $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").show();
    } else {
        $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').hide();
        $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").hide();
    }
  });
}

$(function(){
  initChangeEvent();
  $("#add_fields_placeholder").trigger('change');  
})
```

Comment: It does not seem to load the input box when yes is selected no error

Comment: Still not showing the input for you? I just tried the link and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also place this code in document.ready function. It will work

```
if( $("#add_fields_placeholder").val() == "yes")
{
    $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').show();
    $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").show();
}
else
{

    $('label[for="add_fields_placeholderValue"]').hide();
    $("#add_fields_placeholderValue").hide();
}
    });
```

Comment: It does not seem to load the input box when yes is selected no error